# WPF Binding to Nullable Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums

I have a ComboBox bound to a nullable enum.  The ItemSource is the collection of enum values.  An IValueConverter is used to convert the enum values into strings for display.  Initially the SelectedItem has a value of null as expected.

This all works fine except for the following situation.  The backing model can get reset, basically the nullable enum property gets assigned its original value of null.  When this happens, for some reason, the IValue converter gets called with an empty string.  Why is it being called with an empty string instead of the null value?

Oddly enough the IValueConverter.Convert method never gets called on the initial null value.

EDIT:

The ComboBox is defined as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyProperty}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The source is defined as:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyList" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="MyEnum" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

The backing property is just defined as MyEnum?

Comment: Show the code, particularly the binding, I'm wondering if you can use a `FallbackValue=` in the binding for when its null.

Comment: Wonder if `{x:Type sys:Enum}` and or `TypeName="MyEnum" ` needs to specify that it's nullable?

Comment: Maybe rule out the ItemsSource and just try this on a simple view model property. i.e. simply, `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EnumProp, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />`

Comment: @weston I tried adding DataType="{x:Type MyEnum}" to the DataTemplate, but this seemed to have no effect.  I'm not sure where else you would mark it as nullable.

Comment: Me neither but I'd try either `TypeName="MyEnum?"` or `TypeName="Nullable<MyEnum>"`

Comment: Neither MyEnum? or Nullable<MyEnum> seem to be accepted as valid in the XAML.

Comment: @weston Using TextBlock Text=... instead of a ComboBox does result in null being sent to the IValueConverter instead of the empty string.

Comment: Good, so it is the `ObjectDataProvider` and maybe related to that type not being specified as nullable. I'm not on PC with Visual Studio, so I can't look any more tonight, but hope that's put you on right track.